# how to model a parse class to include isliked, isfollowing fields along with the PFQuery results

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I can't find an efficient way to query Posts(PFObject) or Users(PFUser) classes and also have the isPostLiked(boolean) and isUserFollowed(boolean) included in the results array respectively.

Lets say, I have queried and received 25 Posts from the server. I want to fill in the like heart button with red if I have previously liked this Post. It would be very inefficient to query all the likes of these Posts and see if current user is contained in the results.

Is it possible to write a cloud code function to insert an 'isLiked' field to the query results and return it to the User for instance?

I am open to new strategies since I am stuck here. It is obvious that most of the social apps are having this need as a standard so there must be an effective solution. Thanks

Comment: I would create another class that stores two relations - the user that "likes" the post and the post that the user "likes" (you can do something similar for follows). You can the use a `whereKey:containedIn` query with the array of posts to determine which posts the user likes.  You could write a could code function to retrieve the posts and perform the likers query before returning all of the results.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for quick reply. If my query limit is 25, how many requests would this cloud-code function make to return these results. Also in this case, how will i merge the isLiked field along with the Post object? Is there a way for merging a PFObject with extra fields? I am trying to find a scalable solution. How scalable do you think this solution is?

Comment: Cloud code returns a dictionary, so you would simply put the required objects into a dictionary in JavaScript and return that. I would return an array of posts and and an array of "liked" post object ids. Back on your iOS side you can access the array of post PFObjects and an array of liked objectids (strings). This would be fairly scalable since the query is happening on the parse server; there is less back and forth between your device over the network

Comment: When you said "I would create another class that stores two relations - the user that "likes" the post and the post that the user "likes"", by 'relations' do you mean 'Pointers'?

Comment: Yes, pointer columns

Comment: Ok I understand. So, to be sure, you are telling that basically the cloud-code function does a nested query composed of an outer Posts query which returns 25 Posts and an inside query which uses the 'whereKey:containedIn:'? A total of two requests to the DB. Or is it one outer query and one query for each 25 objects?

Comment: No, two queries. And your cloud code call counts as a request too, so a total of three requests from a billing point of view but hopefully faster and less network traffic that if you performed the two queries directly from your device.

Comment: Wait, what 'count'? I missed that part. And by the way I like your strategy and will try to implement it asap. Would you mind writing an answer so I can check it as an answer?

Comment: parse bills you based on the number of requests per second - up to 30/s is free. Each query is a request but the call to the cloud code function is also a request so there will be three requests. If you have millions of users this may be an issue but probably won't be.

Comment: According to what you are saying, it would not be smart to limit queries to small numbers and spend precious requests for pagination. I think I will increase 25 results to 100 from now on:)

Comment: Yeah, you have to find the right trade off between transfer time (and therefore responsiveness) and number of requests

Answer (score 2):

Your best action is to rid yourself of the relational database thinking. It seems to me you have a separate Likes class that tracks which user likes which post.

In the NoSQL space you should focus on your queries when you plan your datamodel. Ask yourself this question:

> How do I want to query my data?

In this use case, I'm thinking you might want to

- Show how many likes a Post has
- Maybe show which users did like the Post
- Track whether the current user has liked a certain post
- Maybe find all the Posts the current user has liked?

To solve this, I would do the following:

- On the Post class, add a column *likedby*.
- On the User class, add a column *likedposts*. 
  Both these columns are Array columns

Every time a user likes a post, you add a Pointer to the current user to the *likedby* array column for the Post AND a pointer to the post to the *likedposts* array column for the User.

This makes it very easy to

- find how many likes a post has (number of elements in *likedby*)
- list all the users that liked the post (using `query.includeKey("likedby")` on the Post)
- check if the current user has already liked the post (if likedby array contains currentuser)
- list all the posts a user has liked (using `query.includeKey("likedposts")` on the User).

Use the same logic for followings.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. But Parse docs say that Arrays should not be used for more than 100 elements. So it might not be effective when the posts get lots of likes.

Comment: Effectiveness must be measured against its alternatives. Parse also states that the maximum size of an array column is that it must not exceed 128kb (like all other columns). If you expect thousands and thousands of likes, then maybe another approach is preferable. Maybe. You would need to benchmark both approaches. You can check this link: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/new-many-to-many/