# How do I query for objects that haven't been pointed to? (eg. Posts that haven't been flagged)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a `Posts` object. Users flag posts by creating a `Flags` object that has a pointer to the offensive `Posts` object. How do I query for `Posts` that have NOT been flagged? I tried:

```
var postQuery = new Parse.Query("Posts");
var flagQuery = new Parse.Query("Flags");
postQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "post", flagQuery);
```

but flagged posts are not omitted (`objectId` is a string, `post` is a pointer?).

Other ideas (and why I rejected them):

- Execute `flagQuery` separately, create array of flagged post ids, and use `postQuery.notContainedIn("objectId", flagArray);` (this requires an additional request)
- Increment a flagged counter on the `Posts` object (this doesn't let me investigate which users flagged what)
- Store an array of flaggers (users) in the `Posts` object instead of having a `Flags` object (this doesn't let me investigate timestamps)

Comment: I COULD just store the `postId` string instead of the pointer I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

This use case is similar to what I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575755/how-to-model-a-parse-class-to-include-isliked-isfollowing-fields-along-with-the/33596446#33596446).

If you need to also be able to track timestamps for flagging, simply change your model slightly so that you store an array of Flag objects in the Post. You can then add a constraint to your query to only get posts that do do not have Flag objects: `query.whereKeyDoesNotExist("flags")`

Technically I would solve this by adding a cloud code `afterSave()` function for the Flag object that updates the Post object by adding a pointer to the newly created Flag object to the `flags` array column.

**Edit after comment:**
The OP has clarified that it is only posts that have not been flagged by the *current user* he is interested in. As query efficiency is what you want to optimise for, I would then handle this by duplicating data. Keep the array column for flags and add another array column for *flaggedby*. `afterSave()` will then add both a pointer to the Flag object and a pointer to the User object.

Remember that this requires that you will update both columns also if a user "unflags" a post...

To find posts that the current user has NOT flagged, query against the *flaggedby* array like this:

```
[query whereKey:@"flaggedby" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

This will return all posts where the current user is not included in the *flaggedby* array column

Comment: I simplified for my question. I actually want to query for posts that the CURRENT USER hasn't flagged–a simple addition to `flagQuery`. I'd only reject posts globally if they have over 5ish flags. There would be a major performance hit to query array content, right?

Comment: Oh, important clarification. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm now using `addUnique` to store the `flaggedBy` users, and am having trouble determining whether or not to increment the flag count. `addUnique` seems to return "success" whether the user already existed or not. How can I prevent users from flagging a post twice?

Comment: Going this route eliminates the simplicity of CLPs on the `Post` object–security would have to be handled manually through Cloudcode.

Comment: Why are you keeping a counter? Don't use a separate counter. The number of flags are always = number of elements in flag array.

Comment: Because I'd like to filter out `Posts` that have been flagged more than 5 times. AFAIK there is no way to query based on array size.